# Как вывести изображение из sqlite3 в формате blob в QLabel?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, sqlite3

В общем пытаюсь вывести изображение из таблицы -

[image: Табл 1]

Под `3 id` следующим образом -

```
    sqlite_blob_query = """SELECT photo FROM Album WHERE id = 3"""
    cursor.execute(sqlite_blob_query)
    record4 = cursor.fetchall()

    self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_4), _translate(str(record4)))

    cursor.close()
    sqlite_connection.close()
```

И выдаёт ошибку:

> self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_4), _translate(str(record4)))
> TypeError: translate(str, str, disambiguation: str = None, n: int = -1): not enough arguments

Что не так ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я уже как-то вам писал, но попробую еще раз дать вам некоторые советы.

Чтобы получать быстрые и правильные ответы - предоставляйте, пожалуйста,
минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который можно скопировать, запустить
и получить то о чем вы пишите.

По сути. Ошибка в строке

```
self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_4), _translate(str(record4)))
```

> TypeError: translate(str, str, disambiguation: str = None, n: int = -1): 
> недостаточно аргументов

т.к. вы написали   : `_translate(str(record4))`
тогда как ожидается: `_translate(str, str)`

я вообще не понимаю, зачем вы используете `_translate()` ?
Вы можете написать строку, которая выдает ошибку так:

`self.tabWidget.`**`setTabText`**`(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_4), str(record4))`

т.к. согласно документации:

> void QTabWidget::**setTabText**(int index, const QString &label)
>
> Определяет новую метку для страницы на вкладке индекса позиции.

И это совсем не то, что вы спрашиваете в заголовке вопроса:
"Как вывести изображение из sqlite3 в формате blob в QLabel?"

Вы пробовали посмотреть содержимое `record4` ?
Поставьте `print(record4)` после строки `record4 = cursor.fetchall()` и посмотрите.

Одно из возможных решений, того о чем вы спрашиваете,
выглядит как показано в примере ниже.

Скопируйте пример и запуститн его. 
Далее понажимайте кнопку "Выбрать изображение и загрузить в БД" -
загрузите в БД несколько изображений. 
Далее выберите в `combo` , то изображение, которое вы хотите поместить в `label`.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox, QWidget, QApplication, \
    QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QComboBox, QLabel, QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDir, QFile, QFileInfo, QIODevice
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery, QSqlTableModel


def createConnection():
    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
    db.setDatabaseName("testImage.db")
    
    if not db.open():
        QMessageBox.critical(None, "Не удается открыть базу данных ",
                "Не удалось установить соединение с базой данных.\n"
                "Этот пример требует поддержки SQLite. Пожалуйста, прочитайте Qt SQL "
                "документацию для получения информации о том, как ее построить.\n\n"
                "Click Cancel to exit.",
                QMessageBox.Cancel)
        return False

    query = QSqlQuery()
    return query.exec_('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS imgTable
        (id INTEGER primary key AUTOINCREMENT, filename TEXT, imagedata BLOB)''')


class Demo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.load_btn = QPushButton("Выбрать изображение и загрузить в БД")
        self.combo = QComboBox()
        self.label = QLabel()
        
        self.model = QSqlTableModel()
        self.model.setTable("imgTable")
        self.model.select() 
        
        self.combo.setModel(self.model)
        self.combo.setModelColumn(1)
        
        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(self.load_btn)
        vbox.addWidget(self.combo)
        vbox.addWidget(self.label)

        self.load_btn.clicked.connect(self.load_image)
        self.combo.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.on_change_select)

    def on_change_select(self, row):
        ix  = self.combo.model().index(row, 2)
        pix = QPixmap()
        pix.loadFromData(ix.data())
        self.label.setPixmap(pix)

    def load_image(self):
        fname, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self, 
            'Open file', 
            QDir.currentPath(), 
            "Image files (*.jpg, *.gif, *.png)"
        )
        if fname:
            self.saveImage(fname)

    def saveImage(self, filename):
        file = QFile(filename)
        if not file.open(QIODevice.ReadOnly):
            return

        ba = file.readAll()
        name = QFileInfo(filename).fileName()
        
        record = self.model.record()
        record.setValue("filename", name)
        record.setValue("imagedata", ba)

        if self.model.insertRecord(-1, record):
            self.model.select()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    if not createConnection():
        sys.exit(-1)
    w = Demo()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "тогда как ожидается: _translate(str, str)" - благодаря этому пояснению я понял в чём заключалась моя ошибка

Comment: _translate используется видимо из за того, что это происходит во вкладке виджета tabWidget, просто я редактирую уже созданный мной интерфейс в Qt Designer и что откуда пришло особо не разбираюсь, раньше загружал изображение из формы и решил, что лучше всего будет выводить его из бд, т.к. в символах оно занимает очень много строк

Comment: И я понял, что я неправильно действую

Comment: @OverNiko  Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Решив один вопрос, появился другой

Comment: Можете выделить метод вытаскивания самого фото из blob ?

Comment: @OverNiko  метод `on_change_select`

Comment: В ix как я понял попадает в моём случае record1 полученный способом -
        `sqlite_blob_query = """SELECT photo FROM Album WHERE id = 1"""
        cursor.execute(sqlite_blob_query)
        record1 = cursor.fetchone()[0]`

Comment: @OverNiko я чувствую, что вы пытаетесь сделать реализацию используя другой подход. Если у вас что-то не получается - задайте новый вопрос, прикрепите [mcve] , напишите что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.

Comment: Видимо придётся укоротить код для воспроизводимого примера

Comment: Задал новый вопрос